# scanner nextLine() exception: no line found

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm doing the scanner for a static method, and occur this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
```

My modify method tends to get 2 string as input from the console, but it doesn't work.
**NOTE:** I didn't use `scanner.close();`

```
static ArrayList<Book> modBook(){
    Book tempbook = Book.searchTitle();

    if(tempbook !=null){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = BookList.indexOf(tempbook);

        System.out.println("Please enter title:");
        String booktitle = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter author:");
        String bookauthor = sc.nextLine();

        tempbook.setTitle(booktitle);
        tempbook.setAuthor(bookauthor);
        BookList.set(i, tempbook); 

    }
    return BookList;
}
```

My search method:

```
static Book searchTitle(){
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        String booktitle;
        System.out.println("Please enter title:");
        booktitle = input.nextLine();

        for(Book b : BookList){
            if(b.getTitle() != null && b.getTitle().equals(booktitle)){
                System.out.println(b.toString());
                return (Book) b;
            }
        }        
    }catch(Exception e){e.getMessage(); return null;}

    System.out.println("not found");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ?

Comment: You **did** close the scanner. That's the whole point of the try-with-resource statement that you're using in `try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: @JainamJhaveri I want to read two String booktitle and author. Then, set them into a tempbook, but it didn't work

Comment: @JBNizet I thought when we use `(System.in)` to read the InputStream, we shouldn't close for any initialized scanner?  It worked, I think I should read about `try{}catch(){}` a little bit more. Thank you

Comment: @PhiTruong You shouldn't close it, by a try-with-resources statement closes it for you.

Comment: Indeed, you shouldn't close System.in. But you're doing it. Which is the cause of the exception.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to answer it. You can answer your own questions below

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 6):

You are using two instance of *java.util.Scanner* in static methods. You have to used only one instance of *java.util.Scanner*. Remove the two instances of java.util.Scanner and add this as global variable.

```
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Then used input **ONLY** to do all the readings in your code. Make sure you close input when you done with it.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** try-with-resources block close what inside the curve bracket `()`. So, it did close the InputStream, then, just remove it. THANKS

```
static Book searchTitle(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in))
        String booktitle;
        System.out.println("Please enter title:");
        booktitle = input.nextLine();

        for(Book b : BookList){
            if(b.getTitle() != null && b.getTitle().equals(booktitle)){
                System.out.println(b.toString());
                return (Book) b;
        }

    System.out.println("not found");
    return null;
}
```